# How to know the size of payload in response interceptor using grails

Tags: spring, grails, interceptor

I am using grails spring boot for my project. and I am also using interceptors and filters. Currently, I have a test case to include the size of response data. For this, in interceptor, I have integrated the after method of grails interceptor. while debugging, I didn't found any method to know the data size which i sent from my controller. e.g

```
    class RestController {
         def show  {
            def data = [:]
            data.put("object", "some data objects " );

            withFormat {
                json {
                    render wrapper as JSON
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

// interceptor.

```
    class RestInterceptor {

        RestInterceptor(){
            match(controller:"rest", action:"*")
        }

        boolean before() {
            println( request)
            true }

        boolean after() {
            println response
            true
        }

        void afterView() {
            // no-op
        }
    }
```

In response object, Their is not any method to know the content length. However, I can see the same in request object. please give suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

The `after` method is executed after the controller action is invoked and before the view is rendered.  If you want to inspect something in the `model`, you can do that in the `after` method but that doesn't really tell you the size of what is written the response.  If you want the latter, you probably want to use `afterView` instead of `after`.

Comment: Thanks @jeff for reply. I did not found similar response from afterView method too. however i found the alternative by the following which is available in read only mode. we unable to modify it in interceptor.
```
  response.writer.out.charsWritten
  response.writer.out.outputChunk.getBytes().length
```
may be it's not good solution.